# mysqldump not exporting data or structures

Tags: mysql

I have a short PHP script which is supposed to perform a MySQL backup and email it to me. However, neither the data nor the structures are being written by mysqldump. The command to invoke mysqldump looks like this:

```
mysqldump --host=localhost --user=xxx --pass=xxx xxx_license > xxx2012-12-28.sql
```

(The xxx username and password are the same as from another script which works with php and the database so I know the credentials are correct).

The output is as follows:

```
-- MySQL dump 10.13  Distrib 5.5.28, for Linux (x86_64)
--
-- Host: localhost    Database: xxx_license
-- ------------------------------------------------------
-- Server version   5.5.28-cll

/*!40101 SET @OLD_CHARACTER_SET_CLIENT=@@CHARACTER_SET_CLIENT */;
/*!40101 SET @OLD_CHARACTER_SET_RESULTS=@@CHARACTER_SET_RESULTS */;
/*!40101 SET @OLD_COLLATION_CONNECTION=@@COLLATION_CONNECTION */;
/*!40101 SET NAMES utf8 */;
/*!40103 SET @OLD_TIME_ZONE=@@TIME_ZONE */;
/*!40103 SET TIME_ZONE='+00:00' */;
/*!40014 SET @OLD_UNIQUE_CHECKS=@@UNIQUE_CHECKS, UNIQUE_CHECKS=0 */;
/*!40014 SET @OLD_FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS=@@FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS, FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS=0 */;
/*!40101 SET @OLD_SQL_MODE=@@SQL_MODE, SQL_MODE='NO_AUTO_VALUE_ON_ZERO' */;
/*!40111 SET @OLD_SQL_NOTES=@@SQL_NOTES, SQL_NOTES=0 */;

--
-- Current Database: `xxx_license`
--

CREATE DATABASE /*!32312 IF NOT EXISTS*/ `xxx_license` /*!40100 DEFAULT CHARACTER SET latin1 */;

USE `xxx_license`;
```

The CREATE and USE statements are only present if I add --databases to the options.

And using --help to show the default options is:

```
mysqldump  Ver 10.13 Distrib 5.5.28, for Linux (x86_64)

<snip>

Variables (--variable-name=value)
and boolean options {FALSE|TRUE}  Value (after reading options)
--------------------------------- ----------------------------------------
all-databases                     FALSE
all-tablespaces                   FALSE
no-tablespaces                    FALSE
add-drop-database                 FALSE
add-drop-table                    TRUE
add-locks                         TRUE
allow-keywords                    FALSE
apply-slave-statements            FALSE
character-sets-dir                (No default value)
comments                          TRUE
compatible                        (No default value)
compact                           FALSE
complete-insert                   FALSE
compress                          FALSE
create-options                    TRUE
databases                         FALSE
debug-check                       FALSE
debug-info                        FALSE
default-character-set             utf8
delayed-insert                    FALSE
delete-master-logs                FALSE
disable-keys                      TRUE
dump-slave                        0
events                            FALSE
extended-insert                   TRUE
fields-terminated-by              (No default value)
fields-enclosed-by                (No default value)
fields-optionally-enclosed-by     (No default value)
fields-escaped-by                 (No default value)
flush-logs                        FALSE
flush-privileges                  FALSE
force                             FALSE
hex-blob                          FALSE
host                              (No default value)
include-master-host-port          FALSE
insert-ignore                     FALSE
lines-terminated-by               (No default value)
lock-all-tables                   FALSE
lock-tables                       TRUE
log-error                         (No default value)
master-data                       0
max-allowed-packet                25165824
net-buffer-length                 1046528
no-autocommit                     FALSE
no-create-db                      FALSE
no-create-info                    FALSE
no-data                           FALSE
order-by-primary                  FALSE
port                              0
quick                             TRUE
quote-names                       TRUE
replace                           FALSE
routines                          FALSE
set-charset                       TRUE
single-transaction                FALSE
dump-date                         TRUE
socket                            (No default value)
ssl                               FALSE
ssl-ca                            (No default value)
ssl-capath                        (No default value)
ssl-cert                          (No default value)
ssl-cipher                        (No default value)
ssl-key                           (No default value)
ssl-verify-server-cert            FALSE
tab                               (No default value)
triggers                          TRUE
tz-utc                            TRUE
user                              (No default value)
verbose                           FALSE
where                             (No default value)
plugin-dir                        (No default value)
default-auth                      (No default value)
```

If something in those options is wrong, how do I change/override it? I can't find a config file and I don't have SSH access to the web server to perform any actions.

Thanks.

Comment: What do you get if you add '--opt --all-databases'?

Comment: Can you log into the Mysql server ? What does a `SHOW TABLES;` output ?

Comment: Adding '--opt --all-databases' results in one other database CREATE DATABASE and USE being output - and there are 5 databases in the system (the one shown is the first created on the system; no other databases are shown).

Comment: SHOW TABLES (in phpMyAdmin) shows the list of tables in the selected database - no errors or corruption, if that's what you're looking for.

Comment: I tried the debug option too, but I can't see where it's put the trace file, and even specifying the file doesn't seem to produce a file. When debug is used it doesn't output anything to the > output file.

Comment: BTW I'm executing mysqldump with system($command); where $command is the text in the first code line in my question.

Comment: Does `xxx@localhost` have permission to lock all the tables? If not, add `--skip-lock-tables`.

Comment: Add `2>xxx-2012-12-28.err` to the end of the command line, to put errors in the `.err` file. Then examine this file for error messages.

Comment: Seems like your shell script is having restrictions ? Can you export the database using [phpMyAdmin](http://fragments.turtlemeat.com/mysql-database-backup-restore-phpmyadmin.php) ?

Comment: Barmar - that is the correct answer (ie permissions)! Oddly --skip-lock-tables didn't actually work but I checked the user's privileges and it was more restrictive than I thought. Please can you repost your comment as an aswer so I can mark it as the answer? Thanks.

Comment: @Niloct - yes, phpMyAdmin can export the entire database without problems.

Comment: Forgot to link to the user which apparently notifies them - @Barmar - cannot promote a comment to an answer apparently.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Check the user's permissions, and make sure it has SELECT permissions to all the tables. And if it doesn't have permission to lock the tables, use `--skip-lock-tables`.

Comment: Thanks. It had SELECT, UPDATE, INSERT and DELETE but there must have been something else too. I'll whittle it down from full to the minimum required.

Answer (score 2):

I had this same problem in MySql 5.7 trying to just capture the table structure.  I had to explicitly put in --databases  --tables  on the command line in order to get this to work.
For example with data and structure:

```
mysqldump --defaults-extra-file=$confFile --databases $db --tables $tables > ./backup_db.sql
```

Example with just the definition for one table:

```
mysqldump --defaults-extra-file=$confFile -d --databases $db --tables $table > ./table_cre.sql
```

Comment: Thanks! This solved my problem. My output didn't add the DROP TABLE IF EXISTS line. It does after adding --databases before specifying the db.

mysqldump  Ver 10.13 Distrib 5.7.33, for Linux (x86_64)

Answer (score 0):

Try the steps :

mysqldump –u[user-name] –p [database name] > [dump file]

press enter key

password

press enter key

```
mysqldump –uxxx –p xxx_license > xxx2012-12-28.sql

press enter key
```

now enter password

```
xxx

press enter key
```

Works for me.

Comment: Other than prompting for the password instead of passing it as a parameter, how is this different from what he's doing?

Comment: Unfortunately I can't get the php script to "press enter key". The command is obviously being invoked but for whatever reason it's not outputting the table data. The syntax is copied from elsewhere and quadruple checked against the manual. I can't test with SSH either.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue, I resolved it by updating my "mysqldump.exe" to the latest version (the server and my backup server were out of sync in regards to the MySQL version)

Answer (score 0):

Can you run the dump from the command line? If you can't then start there. If you can, since is running through a PHP script, make sure your script has permission to write to the directory it is saving the dump to. Check the owner/group permissions and the permissions of the directory being saved to.

Answer (score 0):

In my case I was uncontiously using wrong workbench version. Thus used mysqldump which did not export all rows, fortunately I checked couple of tables :).

Solution: https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/183241/mysqldump-not-exporting-all-rows-or-mysql-not-importing

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/31776911)